# What is the most efficient algorithm to detect and remove duplicates in a Collection?

Tags: java, collections

What is the most efficient way to detect and remove duplicates in any Collection? I use the following method:

```
static class Link{
    Link(Link next1,Object val1){
        next = next1;
        val = val1;
    }
    Link next;
    Object val;
}
public static void removeDuplicates(Collection<?> collection){
    Link link = null;
    Iterator<?> itr = collection.iterator();
    a: while(itr.hasNext()){//Iterate the parameter Collection or corrupted Set
        Object obj = itr.next();
        Link c = link;
        while(c != null){
            if(obj.equals(c.val)){
                itr.remove();//Duplicate found!
                continue a;
            }
            c = c.next;
        }
        link = new Link(link,obj);
    }
}
```

Is there a faster (or better) way to remove duplicates?

Comment: Why do you put mutable objects in a set and then manipulate their contents? Why are you ignoring warnings **not** to do that? What are you trying to do, there's probably a lot better way than constantly checking your set while you corrupt it.

Comment: remove the object from the set -> manipulate the object -> add the object to the set

Comment: The fastest way to solve your problem is to step back and look at the mess you are about to create; and to then re-think your approach and find a better solution. Anything else is a **fast** route to into chaos. The point is: the Set decides things when **adding** new objects. The idea to "re-compute" itself completely on already added objects is **absolutely** "alien" to the set class (imho).

Comment: As Kayaman already said, having mutable objects in a `HashSet` (or as keys in a `HashMap` - which actually is that `HashSet` is doing internally) is a bad idea if `hashCode()` and `equals()` could be affected by the modification. The problems you're having are just one indicator for this.

Comment: Btw: "I use a HashSet to manipulate a set of mutalbe objects" - how do you use a set to _manipulate_ objects? I'd guess you mean you are manipulating objects _in_ that set, don't you? If so you could try to build a new set, i.e. iterate over the set, remove the objects (or clear the original set at the end of the loop), manipulate them and add them to a new set . That should take care of duplicates automagically.

Comment: Great... I lose my option to ask another question, and I don't even get an answer! I want an answer, not excuses.

Comment: @Gergely: I don't understand your attitude. You got several answers and advice from experienced developers. But you are ignorant and imperious.

Answer (score 1):

If you change an object in a hash-based collection such that the hashcode / equals contract is violated, the behavior of the set is unspecified.  It certainly isn't guaranteed to have "set like" semantics with respect to the API.  Thus, there is no solution to your problem that the specs (i.e. the javadoc) will *guarantee* to work.

In practice, the *most-likely-to-work* solution would be to iterate the set entries and add them to a new (empty) set.  Using `addAll` would be equivalent.  This is (of course) very expensive.

But the real solution is to avoid getting the problem in the first place.  If you put mutable objects into collections that rely on stable equality & hashcodes OR stable ordering, then remove them before you mutate them; e.g.

```
set.remove(e);
e.mutate();
set.add(e);
```